# Create a branch with Jenkins with the Jira Issue Key

Tags: jenkins, jira, jenkins-jira-trigger

I'm building a Continous Integration environment with Jira, Jenkins and GitLab. One of the things I need is that every time an issue is created in Jira, a branch is created in Gitlab, with the same name as the issue of Jira, using a job by Jenkins.

### Using the Jira trigger Plugin for Jenkins I get that every time an issue is created, the job is launched to create the branch, but what I can not do is read the name of the issue from the jira trigger to name the gitlab branch. Do you know what I can do?

I solved it using the JIRA_ISSUE_KEY variable that it's sent to Jenkins.

Comment: Have you tried using the `Issue Attribute Path` feature and get the name of the issue out?

Comment: I solved this using the JIRA_ISSUE_KEY variable that is send by the Jira trigger plugin to Jenkins in each call, this is the identifier of the issue.

Comment: You mentioned "name" in your original question. You might want to change your question and add your own answer.